# with the window.onload some functions values arent been read (ts6133 )

Tags: javascript

the function `gastoMayor(){}`; gives me an error of : is declared but its value is never read.

dont know what to do

```
window.onload = function () {

  function gastosMayor (persona){
    let gastoM = 0;
    for (const key in persona) {
      console.log(key);
      if (persona[key].gastos > gastoM) {
        gastoMayor = persona[key].gastos; 
      }
    }
    return ('El miembro que mas gasto, gasto: ' + gastoM);
  }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

It's not an error, it's a warning.

On the very first line of the function, you define `gastoM`, which you subsequently use to compare with, but never change the value of.

Meanwhile, you keep setting this `gastoMayor` variable but you never actually use it - and that's the one that is throwing the warning.

I am guessing you are looking for the "highest" gasto, whatever that is (as mayor/major/meyor typically means "highest"). So, modify your code to be this:

```js
let personaTest = [
 { name: 'foo', gastos: 2},
 { name: 'bar', gastos: 3}
];
function gastosMayor(persona) {

  let gastoM = 0;

  for (const key in persona) {
    console.log(key);
    if (persona[key].gastos > gastoM) {
      gastoM = persona[key].gastos;

    }
  }
  return ('El miembro que mas gasto, gasto: ' + gastoM);

}

console.log(gastosMayor(personaTest));
```

This both gets rid of the variable (as you no longer have a write-only variable) and potentially the issue.

If this solved your issue, in the future, when you ask a question on SO, briefly describe what the code **should** do. It typically not only helps answerers, but will help you find issues like these.

Comment: Based on the code `personaTest` should probably be an object rather than an array.

Comment: @Andy I don't know, if the iteration key was `name` I'd agree. `key` could be either, and I'm not sure if the OP knows about `let ... of ...`. Can probably edit